# gRPC C++: any way to retrieve a detailed error message when grpcServerReaderWriter's Read() or Write() returns false?

Tags: c++, grpc

In gRPC C++, is there any way to retrieve a detailed error message when grpcServerReaderWriter's Read() or Write() returns false?

The header file(sync_stream.h)'s comment just says: "return true on success, false when the stream has been closed." But I want to know 'why' the stream has been closed (maybe prematurely).

On the client side, I can call Finish() after Write() returns false and retrieve the error message in the status that Finish() returns. But on the server side there is no Finish(), so no error message.

Thank you in advance.